# Domain and codomain of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, definition, education

I'm wondering if it is correct to say that:

1. the domain of a sequence is a discrete domain made by positive integer (the zero is included);
2. the domain of a sequence is a continuous domain made by real number.

If possible can you suggest me also references in which I can find a formal definiton please?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual formal definition of sequence is:

> A function $a:\Bbb N\to X$,

where $X$ is the set of interest. Also, it is costumary to accept sequences to be indexed by sets in the form $\{n\in\Bbb Z\,:\, z\ge m\}$.

Comment: Hello @Gae.S. thus the zero is not included in the domain?

Comment: $0\in \Bbb N{}$

Comment: But having sequences start with $a_1$ just as common, if not more common.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gae.S.